# Weird label bug. wont let me set the text why is that?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am receiving a struct from a server app and when the client program gets it and its the type of serverInfo it sends it to a functions and sets the server info to labels.  I have put MessageBox.Show() on both ends to see whats wrong and the first one pops up but the second doesnt.  The first messagebox shows the info from the struct recived from the server and its all correct so i know that works. I have also put a Message box between each of the label.text = text and they didnt show. I also tried just putting "this is a test string" on them and they still didnt do anything.

Edit* this is WinForms

Edit* I found out that it is a cross threading problem so whats a good way to change labels from another thread?

```
private void onServerInfo(msgBox message)
{
    serverInfo.info info = (serverInfo.info)message.getMessage("info");
    MessageBox.Show(info.name + " ; " + info.type + " ; " + info.limit); // works with everything showing up right
    ServerName.Text = info.name; //this is a string
    ServerType.Text = info.type.ToString(); // this is a enum
    MaxLimit.Text = info.limit.ToString(); // this is a int
    MessageBox.Show(ServerName.Text + " ; " + ServerType.Text + " ; " + MaxLimit.Text); // doesnt ever show
}
```

Comment: Is there some random exception? If you were to debug each step, what happens? Can you see the value of the struct on each line? Or does your debugger suddenly stop debugging? The reason being, there's no good reason the call to MessageBox.Show() doesn't show up, unless it's never called... Maybe it's some cross-threading access exception.

Comment: there is no errors and it keeps debuging but i put a breakpoint after servername.text and it never reached it so i put it on servername.text and it reached that so its just pausing at servername.text = info.name also its winForms

Comment: Right so, if it's stopping, there must be an exception. Perhaps you're trying to access your form controls from another thread (the network thread)? Try surrounding your code with a try {} catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); }

Comment: @Yuck that's why I asked. If he is working in ASP, then `MessageBox.Show()` will behave exactly as he is describing. He's better off doing a `Response.Write()`... ***EDIT**: ah, I missed the bit where he said the first `.Show()` works*

Comment: Ok so its the cross threading, whats a good way to change it from another thread? i tried an event but it had the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your exception is caused by a cross-threading access exception, use this handy method to fix that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2242393/555547

So edit your class to be like:

```
/// <summary>
  /// Extension method that allows for automatic anonymous method invocation.
  /// </summary>
  public static void Invoke(this Control c, MethodInvoker mi)
  {
     c.Invoke(mi);

     return;
  }


private void onServerInfo(msgBox message)
{
this.Invoke
(
   () =>
   {
    serverInfo.info info = (serverInfo.info)message.getMessage("info");
    MessageBox.Show(info.name + " ; " + info.type + " ; " + info.limit); // works with everything showing up right
    ServerName.Text = info.name; //this is a string
    ServerType.Text = info.type.ToString(); // this is a enum
    MaxLimit.Text = info.limit.ToString(); // this is a int
    MessageBox.Show(ServerName.Text + " ; " + ServerType.Text + " ; " + MaxLimit.Text); // doesnt ever show
   }
);
}
```

Though for good practice, you should really put that extension method in it's own file called ControlExtensions.cs and call it from there.

*Edit:* Actually, you must put that extension method in it's own static class or you'll get an error.

Comment: cannot convert lambda expression to delegate is an error i got when i tried that

Comment: Try adding 'using System.Linq;' to your directives.

Comment: oh lol i forgot i took that off the top, that fixed it now everything works thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me assure, you that there is nothing wrong with the piece of code that you have shown - the problem is elsewhere.

The fact is that your breakpoint is hit on the `ServerName.Text` line but is not hit on the next line means that this line produces an exception.

The fact that your application does not crush indicates that this exception is silently swallowed somewhere, usually not a good thing and something that complicates troubleshooting (like in your case), so if this is something you can fix, I'd encourage you to do so.

One of the things you can do in Visual Studio, is to go in the "Debug" menu and selecting the "Exceptoins..." item. The dialog that comes up will allow you to make sure that the debugger will stop on swallowed exceptions too, this might shed some light on the situation and can be a useful debugging technique.

The first thing that you need to do is to find out what exception is being thrown. This will give you new information to work off. One way of finding it out I explained above, but sometimes, when there are a lot of exceptions being thrown and caught it is not very practical. In this case you can **temporarily** wrap your problem code in a try/catch block like this:

```
private void onServerInfo(msgBox message)
{
    try 
    {
      serverInfo.info info = (serverInfo.info)message.getMessage("info");
      MessageBox.Show(info.name + " ; " + info.type + " ; " + info.limit); // works with everything showing up right
      ServerName.Text = info.name; //this is a string
      ServerType.Text = info.type.ToString(); // this is a enum
      MaxLimit.Text = info.limit.ToString(); // this is a int
      MessageBox.Show(ServerName.Text + " ; " + ServerType.Text + " ; " + MaxLimit.Text); // doesnt ever show
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Put your break point on the `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` and examine contents of the exception. This will allow you to progress on your issue.

At this point we could have stopped, but let us think what could be possible causes of the issue.

As someone else pointed out, most likely the problem is that you are trying to access an UI element form non-UI thread, which is something that is not allowed in a .NET application. You can read more about here [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171728%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The basic idea is that you need to use InvokeRequired/Invoke methods on your UI controls to access them from another thread.

Another possible reason of a error could be that for whatever reason your `ServerName` is null.