# How to exit a process by catching a mouse click?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, just beginning to write some codes.
I have something in mind but before proceeding to it, need some help on this matter.
How to exit a running process by detecting a mouse click?
I wrote some lines but when compiled and running, the mouse click has no effect at all.
Can someone please take a look and help me?
Here's my lines...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Graphic_test_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            public static Single lim_x, lim_y; // limits in X & Y
            public static int dly = 45;
            System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue); // color of the pen
            System.Drawing.Graphics Canvas;
            public Boolean clik = false; // initialize
            public string mystring;
            public Form1()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                    base.OnMouseClick(e);
                    clik = true;
                    lim_x = e.X;
                    lim_y = e.Y;
            }

            private void btgo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start drawing  [GO]
            {
                    Canvas = this.CreateGraphics();
                    btgo.Enabled = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Checking the limits of the canvas.\r\n" +
                            "Click anywhere to stop and find out X position",
                            "Watching Coordinates",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    btgo.Visible = false;
                    btend.Enabled = false;

                    myPen.Color=System.Drawing.Color.Red; // color of the pen
                    myPen.Width = 2; // pen width
                    System.Drawing.Font drawfont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10); // Graphics font
                    System.Drawing.SolidBrush mybrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black); // color for the font
                    System.Drawing.Color background;
                    background = this.BackColor;

                    lim_x = 0; // initialize
                    do
                    {
                            Canvas.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 200, lim_x, 200);
                            mystring = "Current X = " + lim_x.ToString();
                            mybrush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            Canvas.DrawString(mystring, drawfont, mybrush, 351, 334);
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(dly);
                            mybrush.Color = background; // use the background color
                            Canvas.FillRectangle(mybrush, new Rectangle(350, 333, 500, 353));
                            if (clik)
                            {
                                    mybrush.Color = background; // use the background color
                                    Canvas.FillRectangle(mybrush, new Rectangle(350, 333, 500, 353));
                                    mystring = "Current X = " + lim_x.ToString();
                                    mybrush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                                    Canvas.DrawString(mystring, drawfont, mybrush, 351, 334);
                                    MessageBox.Show("Final position in X = " + lim_x.ToString(),
                                            "Mouse click detected",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                                    break;
                            }
                            else
                                    lim_x++;
                    } while (lim_x < 611);

                    myPen.Dispose(); // release the pen
                    mybrush.Dispose(); // release the brush
                    Canvas.Dispose(); // release the canvas
                    btend.Enabled = true;
                    btend.Focus();
            }

            private void btend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // quit program  [END]
            {
                    Dispose(); // program ends.
            }

    }
```

}

Comment: Is `btend_Click` wired up to your button? You'd need to look at the designer file as well to make sure.

Comment: Are you trying to exit your own app or another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you are trying to stop the process it are running. (e.g. The btgo click event).

To do this, you should use an individual `Thread` to execute the process.

**Why Thread ?**

Your application will run two different process :

1. The main `Thread`
2. The second `Thread`

So, it will be possible to recognize the "Mouse Click" while you are running the second `Thread`.

E.g. I have one `Button` and one `Label`. I want, on the `Button1` click,create and start a `Thread`. This `Thread` will loop 10000 time and modify the `Label1` text. But when I click on the label, the loop will stop :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

public partial class Test : Form
{

    Thread thread;
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartThread));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void StartThread()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<1000000;i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Label1.Text = i.ToString())); 
            //See the more information section, I will post a link about this.

        }
    }

    void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

**More information :**

1. You should read about how to properly close a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327102/how-to-kill-a-thread-instantly-in-c).
2. Invoke method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172467/set-value-of-label-with-c-sharp-cross-threading).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to close your form, use `this.Close()`. if you want to exit your application, you can use `Application.Exit()`.