# Change label text using threading- C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates

I need to display the members of an array one-by-one into a label using thread. The thread needs to change the content every second. How could I achieve this?

My code is as follows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] heartRate = new String[] {"153","155","157","155","153","154"};
    myThread display = new myThread();

    display.hr =  Array.ConvertAll(heartRate, num => Int32.Parse(num));

    Thread threadHeartRate = new Thread(display.threadHeartrate);   
}

public class myThread
{
    private int[] _hr;
    internal int[] hr  {get { return _hr; } set { _hr = value; } }
    public void threadHeartrate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _hr.Length; i++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The array I need to print is `heartRate`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172467/set-value-of-label-with-c-sharp-cross-threading

Comment: Do you really need a thread (as an exercise or something)? Otherwise I would prefer a simple [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a WinForms application? Please tag your post accordingly.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not sure if this dupehammer is the best help. This thread is full of very outdated and verbose code, while OP would have probably best been helped with a simple [`Progress<int>´](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: yes, I need to use thread. It is an exercise on multithreaded programming.